# Why new File() should not be put into try block, but new FileReader("input.txt") should be in a try block?

Tags: java

I am learning how to read file in java. This difference troubled me. I think there is underlining difference that I don't quite know.

```
File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
// is perfect fine even if input.txt doesn't exist. Why?

// but
FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
// should be put into try.. catch block?? or compiler error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical reason is because one constructor throws a non runtime exception and the other does not.

As for why? Perhaps because the File class is just an abstraction around a file system path name. It doesn't really matter whether the file exists at that path. A FileReader encapsulates a read operation on an actual file system object and throws an exception if the file doesn't exist or otherwise cannot be open for reading.

Answer (score 4):

Because `new FileReader("file")` throws the checked exception `FileNotFoundException` where `new File("file")` doesn't.

Note that `new File` doesn't check if the file actually exists or not, where `FileReader` does.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is just an object representing a file name:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

While a [`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) is an open resource used for reading the content of a file, and implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html):

> A resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

`File("input.txt")` is not yet committed to an actual file. So you can test if file exists or open the file for writing at a later point. While `FileReader("input.txt")` actually tries to open the named file for reading, and hence can throw an exception.